# IE6 https security message appearing after closing jQuery colorbox overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am working on a secure site, https.

I am using the colorbox jquery plugin to iframe another page from the same site over the current content.

In IE6 when i close the colorbox overlay i get the following message:

"This page contains both secure and nonsecure items.

Do you want to display the nonsecure items?"

Any ideas why this is happening?  Can it be prevented?

Assume i would have to make the whole site http rather than https but this is not possible as we have online payments.

Comment: Why are you loading content from a third party site in an iframe on a page on which you take payment information?

Comment: @ David.

I am loading content from my own site via the iFrame from colorbox.  It is a functional JSP and did not seem to work an other way.

Comment: Mixed content detection in IE6 is quite buggy.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/HTTPS-Mixed-Content-in-IE8.aspx and particularly the comments for troubleshooting steps to find the request url being treated as insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a cure for this courtesy of the creator:

http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/2d307504b4782d68#

Answer (score 2):

To avoid that message you need to serve all of your content (including jQuery libraries) using https. So:

```
<script src="http://example.com/js/...
```

Would need to change to:

```
<script src="https://example.com/js/...
```

Comment: … and you would have to load the content of the iframe over HTTPS too.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether all elements of the page loaded on secure protocol. If the site you use and http and https, then I would suggest to specify the url as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com/js/...">
```

Comment: interesting... i'll have to try doing url's like that,  I never knew about that